# Sphere projection angles equivalence

Tags: math, 3d, geometry, projection

Let's suppose we have a sphere of radius r at a distance d from the observer

We define the following

```
O: observer
C: Center of the sphere
P: arbitrary visible point of the sphere (fromthe observer)

OC: line connecting the observer to the center of the sphere ( fixed length: d)
OP: Line connecting the observer and an arbitrary visible point of the sphere (variable length depending on the angle: a)
CP: Line connecting the center of the sphere and this arbitrary visible point (fixed length: r)


theta: angle between OC and OP
shi: angle between OC and CP
```

In case P is one of the "external" visible points of the sphere, using basic geometry we have that

```
theta_max = atan( r/ sqrt(d^2-r^2) )
shi_max = PI/2 - theta_max
```

For any other point, I got the following equations

```
r.cos(shi) + a.cos(theta) = d
r.sin(shi) = a.sin(theta)
```

I think these equations are right, but I can see no way to write them as shi=f(theta), since 'a' also varies with it.

Is it possible? Or is any of these steps wrong?

**EDIT**

Working with the latest two equations, we can get

```
tan(theta)= r.sin(shi)/(d-r.cos(shi))
```

but I would need to get shi=f(theta) if possible

Comment: You want to eliminate one variable (`a`) from two equations, which is easy here.  You solve one equation for `a`, and put the result into the other.  Then `a` is gone and you can solve it for `shi`.

Comment: thanks pentadecagon, but if I do it I can only get tan(theta)=r.sin(shi)/(d-r.cos(shi)), which gives me theta as a function of shi, but I cannot get its reciprocal shi = f(theta) if it exists in a closed form (which I don't know). editing the post to point this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's call the angle between CP and OP `λ`.  Solving for `λ` is rather simple:

```
sin(λ) = sin(theta)*d/r
```

Now you know two angles within that triangle and the remaining one can be calculated from the angle sum of a triangle:

```
shi = Pi - theta - asin( sin(theta)*d/r )
```